# Combine duplicate for loop results

Tags: python

I'm trying to categorize some sentences which looks to be working now. The problem I'm running into is when the code below finds multiple words/key values in a sentence, it gets displayed in the output as separate lines.

Is there a way to group the sentences as one and have the categories separated with a ","? So for example the output below for the ID: 4309168592 - would be combined and have both categories of "Price, Product Quality"

Code Output:

```
4309168592 ,  Great price on the dewalt saw. Good quality product ,  price
4309168592 ,  Great price on the dewalt saw. Good quality product ,  product_quality
4309842152 ,  cool deal and quality ,  product_quality
4308854280 ,  love it! and the price percent off ,  price
4308854280 ,  love it! and the price percent off ,  price
```

Also here is the code:

```
data = ["Great price on the dewalt saw. Good quality product", "cool deal and quality", "love it! and the price percent off", "definitely going to buy"]
words = {'price': ['price', 'compare', '$', 'percent', 'money', '% off'],
         'product_quality': ['quality', 'condition', 'aspect']}


for d in data:
    for category, word in words.items():
        for s in word:
            if s in d:
                print(id(d), ", ", d, ", ", category)
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplication is the result of iteration over `word`. You can replace is with a single condition:

```py
for d in data:
    for category, word in words.items():
        if set(d) & set(word):
            print(id(d), ", ", d, ", ", category)
```

The `&` performs set intersection, and we check that the intersection is not empty. But you might prefer a more legible version (but slightly less efficient), using list comprehension:

```py
for d in data:
    for category, word in words.items():
        if any(s in d for s in word):
            print(id(d), ", ", d, ", ", category)
```